# Pulling sub arrays out of larger array

Tags: php, arrays

I bought a script known as CoinDice, and I need to take the output array and create a PHP code that will pull everyone of these values: EX. [0],[1],[3],[4] and so on. In the arrays I would like to capture the amount, address, txid, category, confirmations.

```
Array
(
    [transactions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 8.131E-5
                    [blockhash] => 00000000000000001bb164ff85fe78f5f54bde00d4462d8bef19f96421334673
                    [address] => 1HJqsE5CoPnVSPvQVKU4oPCVku47eu39kr
                    [fee] => 0.0001
                    [txid] => 75c9ad12fdbe957ad3c98edfc02fa212dde0ca8e941373c82df5c545599936ce
                    [label] => 
                    [time] => 1415703105
                    [category] => receive
                    [confirmations] => -394
                    [blockindex] => 490989
                    [account] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (


                    [amount] => 1.5E-5
                    [blockhash] => 000000000000000001fd1bc6e7add41bbca9e4d77a43ccd430a144c70c08d985
                    [address] => 16GttENVpxmq1oZjnP5TkLWDrwi3HBa1iu
                    [fee] => 0.0001
                    [txid] => 29420d9a380df6546920a7cd5da5f9750219ef8e1102f2194547a38323e6dfd7
                    [label] => 
                    [time] => 1415453123
                    [category] => receive
                    [confirmations] => -815
                    [blockindex] => 489453
                    [account] => 
                )
```

Answer (score 2):

All you do is a simple `foreach` loop like so:

```
foreach($array['transactions'] as $key => $object) {
    // The $key would be the [0], [1], [2], etc...
    // Here I am just echoing the values to the page,
    // but you can do your code stuff here.
    echo  $object['amount'];
    echo  $object['blockhash'];
    echo  $object['address'];
    // etc...
}
```

The `foreach` will run down your `array()` and apply your code to each sub-array.

**To access the values directly:**

```
echo $array['transactions'][0]['amount'];
echo $array['transactions'][0]['blockhash'];
//...etc.

echo $array['transactions'][1]['amount'];
echo $array['transactions'][1]['blockhash'];
//...etc.
```

Hopefully this ends your 3-week long headache.

Answer (score 0):

Something like.

```
$yourArray = ....

foreach($yourArray['transactions'] as $values){
 echo $values; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you only have access to the output as shown in your question, not the actual array as PHP code.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#77958) for a function that will parse `print_r()` style output back into an array. I've tested it on a trivial array example, so it *might* work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understood your question is that you want to fetch your data under "transactions" array,

suppose you have array name sample,

so you can simply use foreach loop lik

```
foreach($sample['transactions'] as $transaction)    
{    
echo $transaction['amount'];
}
```